# size of char is not consistent between an array and string

Tags: c

if you have

```
char test1[]  = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char test2[]  = "abc";
```

I understand `sizeof(test1)` is 3 since char is only 1 byte hence 1x3 = 3

BUT why isnt the `sizeof(test2)` 3? y is it 4?

Comment: One more for the terminating `'\0'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test2 is actually a terminated string so one more char for this '\0' so the size is 4.

```
 test2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

Answer (score 2):

String literals are arrays that have an implicit additional, final element with value zero. That's the convention used by various `str`-functions (e.g. in `<string.h>` to tell then end of a string even if you only give them a pointer to the beginning.

Colloquially, we say that "C strings are null-terminated", even though C doesn't really have strings - just arrays of characters with some conventions. (The conventions are rather brittle, as you just demonstrated yourself: You can pass both `test1` and `test2` to a string function, with varying levels of disastrous results.)

Comment: C really does have strings. A *string* is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character" (ISO C standard, section 7.1.1). What C doesn't have is a string *type*.